# Show mouse pointer (sticky keys shift 5 times style)

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a .NET program that reproduces mouse clicks however i would like to have it show that it is actually clicking,

is there a way to programatically trigger this sticky key things that shows circles around the mouse when you press shift 5 times?

Or for that matter maybe another effect just to make it clear for the user that the mouse is there and it is clicking right now. I also wish to avoid to have to actually activate sticky keys for the user since they're very annoying in my opinion.

I love you all, you make my days at work great and I take this occasion to thank you all for teaching me all the good stuff i learnt here. (:

Comment: Do the mouse clicks happen only within the window(s) of your application or anywhere (other applications, windows desktop etc.)?

Comment: other applications, windows desktop, internet browser, anything you actually want to have it click.

Comment: You could create a window there (where you going to click) and draw something inside (a gif, an animation, a movie, *Titanic* is the best).